# Android Mapbox MarkerViewOptions anchor not working

Tags: android, mapbox

I am trying to draw a marker on the mapbox map. The issue is the marker is anchored on its top left edge. However i would like this to be center bottom. Although Mapbox claims this is the default behavior, i am not seeing it.

One thing i noticed is if i place the default marker then its anchored correctly. But if i use a markerview then its anchored top-left. I tried setting the anchor value to (0.5f,1.0f) but nothing happens.

This is the code for your reference. Any help will be appreciated.

```
        MarkerView userMarker = map.addMarker(new SampleMarkerViewOptions()
                .position(stationLatLng)
                .anchor(0.5f,1.0f));
```

For reference purpose i am showing the current view and the expected view which is only possible using the default marker.

[image: Expected outcome. So far possible only using default marker.]

[image: Current outcome using markerview]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Marker anchoring looks to be working as expected on custom marker views. Could you clarify which version of the SDK you are using and try using the latest SNAPSHOT to see if it fixes the issue. You also look to be possibly using a device with marker view issues (green background on view).

[image]

Include this in the your `build.gradle` file to use SNAPSHOT:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"     }
}

dependencies {
    compile ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:4.2.0-SNAPSHOT@aar') {
        transitive=true
    }
}
```

Comment: i guess i am using SDK 4.1.1 (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:4.1.1@aar). I didnt understand the meaning of latest SNAPSHOT can you please explain? Also the green background was set by me to highlight the anchor issue.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to change the dependency to SNAPSHOT.

Comment: ​I was able to reproduce your issue on 4.1.1, you have a few options to resolve this issue. Update the Mapbox dependency to either 4.2.0-beta.5 or use the SNAPSHOT (nightly) build. The issue has been resolved in the those versions. A second option would be to use gl markers rather then marker views. simply change your add marker code to use MarkerOptions instead of MarkerViewOptions. The downside to using GL markers are that you don't have as much customization but if you are just displaying a custom marker icon this option would be suitable for your use case.